# integration custom JS with odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo

I have a custom code with html css and Js and I want to make integration with odoo 
for the first time i put the code html and css in my form view it's okay but i want to add javascript 
this is the code I want to add to my module

https://codepen.io/maesi/pen/CAydp

```
  function viewGraph(){
 $('.column').css('height','0');
$('table tr').each(function(index) {
var ha = $(this).children('td').eq(1).text();
$('#col'+index).animate({height: ha}, 1500).html("<div>"+ha+"</div>");
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 viewGraph();
 });
```

if someone have an tuto or documentation how to be good in Js Odoo thnx to add here

Comment: Is this of any help? https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-can-i-add-javascript-code-to-new-module-in-odoo-11-how-to-add-template-and-access-to-python-model-data-126212

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, JS framework is really hard for an odoo rookie.
I search for a solution for css combine JS works too.
And finally, got some progress.
this is some trick for implement css in some condition.

```xml
<!-- add the code in your view template -->
<template id="assets_backend_weight" name="static assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/your_module/static/src/js/jsfile.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
```

```
odoo.define('your_module.jsfile', function (require) {"use strict";
    var core = require('web.core');
    var Widget = require('web.Widget');

    var bgdrawer = Widget.extend({
        /* <init: construct before loading DOM completely.>*/
        init: function() {
            var self = this;
            self._super.apply(this, arguments);
             //self.bgChanger();
             /*  this is used to register a listener on an event.
                  form: .on(ev, node.callback, node.context);
                   ev:
                      'resize': implement when browser resize
                      'DOM_updated': implement when DOM updated
                      ...etc.                                      */
             core.bus.on('click', "div[name='in_out'] div input:checked", self.bgChanger);
             core.bus.on('DOM_updated', "span[name='in_out']", self.post_bgChanger);
             core.bus.on('click', "button .o_pager_next", self.post_bgChanger);
        },
        bgChanger: function() {
            var v = $("div[name='in_out'] div input:checked").attr('data-value');
            if (v =='O') { $('.o_form_sheet').css("background-color","#adff2f");}
            else if(v =='I') { $('.o_form_sheet').css("background-color","#ffc0cb");}
        },
        post_bgChanger: function() {
            if ($("span[name='in_out']")[0]){
                var _str = $("span[name='in_out']")[0].innerHTML;
                if (_str=="出貨") { $('.o_form_sheet').css("background-color","#adff2f");}
                else if(_str=="進貨") { $('.o_form_sheet').css("background-color","#ffc0cb");}
            }
        },
    });


    var my_widget = new bgdrawer(this);
    my_widget.appendTo($(".o_form_sheet"));

});
```

the effect like this
[image]
[image]

this took me a lot of time to achieve, so if you get work.
please vote for my answer.

In your case, I think the first step is to extend widget and define the function in it.
And construct listener to envent DOM_updated.

```
var your_widget = Widget.extend({
    init: function() {
            var self = this;
            self._super.apply(this, arguments);

            core.bus.on('DOM_updated', self, self.viewGraph);
    },

    viewGraph: function() {
        // your code
    },
})
```

and don't forget to call the widget.

```
var my_widget = new your_widget(this);
    my_widget.appendTo($(".o_form_sheet"));
```